# Special type of dataset in BigQuery?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

While having a look at the numerous public datasets in BigQuery, I came across some datasets whose icon was slightly different:

[image]

As you can see, "crypto_kusama" and "crypto_polkadot" both have an extra symbol on their icon. But I couldn't find any information in the description of those datasets or in GCP's documentation.

Does anyone know what this special icon means?

Comment: is it not public datasets?

Comment: Hi@guillaume, Did the answer below help you?

Comment: Hi. Yes, I first had a look at the documentation (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/analytics-hub-introduction) and then at a Medium article on the topic (https://medium.com/google-cloud/google-cloud-analytics-hub-f30fde439e4b) and the icon that we see is indeed the one I was talking about. Case closed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a linked data set and thats why the sign is having symbolic link sing in the dataset icon.
A linked dataset is a read-only BigQuery dataset that serves as a symbolic link to a shared dataset.